# Have computer only go to sleep (or turn off monitors) when video isn't playing?

Tags: windows-8, sleep

Is it possible to have my computer shut off its monitors or go to sleep after say 5 minutes, but only if video is not playing?

Comment: I'm not sure which application you're using to play back video, but for me at least, this is already the behaviour of Windows 8 when using the metro video player app or media centre.  I just have the normal power settings configured.  I haven't tried media player or VLC (or other players) so can't say about those.

Comment: This is in VLC.

Comment: Odd, it does work. I just assumed it wouldn't. I wonder if it will work for playing audio as well.

Comment: Update: this does now work for Netflix, but does work for VLC.

Comment: Odd - I'm sure I've run the Netflix app with no problems when I had a trial subscription (I found not enough content here - UK - to be worthwhile continuing).  Are you using the Metro-style App, or inside a browser?

Comment: Chrome version 24.0 on 64bit Windows 8